# Apexcharts: is it possible to show a subset of a given series? I need to focus only last 5 elements of a series by default...not the entire series

Tags: vue.js, apexcharts

I need to focus only on the last 5 elements of array and allow pan to show the other part of my series. Is it possible?
[Here my example](https://codepen.io/zedmax/pen/JjPmKRK)

````
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    toolbar: {
          show: true,
          tools: {
            download: false,
            selection: true,
            zoom: true,
            zoomin: true,
            zoomout: true,
            pan: true,
            reset: true | '<img src="/static/icons/reset.png" width="20">',
            customIcons: []
          },
          autoSelected: 'zoom' 
        },
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'sales',
    data: [30,40,45,50,49,60,70,91,125]
  }],
  xaxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    categories: ['01/01/1991','01/01/1992','01/01/1993','01/01/1994','01/01/1995','01/01/1996','01/01/1997', '01/01/1998','01/01/1999']
  }
}

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);

chart.render(); ```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Check out  [my example](https://codepen.io/zedmax/pen/JjPmKRK).

It's very easy: to show only a subset of your data you need to set the `xaxis` min value.